# Entering values at each index of dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe which I am storing information about different objects in a video.

For each frame of the video I'm saving the positions of the objects in a dataframe with columns 'x', 'y' 'particle' with the frame number in the index:

```
         x     y  particle
frame                     
0      588   840         0
0      260   598         1
0      297  1245         2
0      303   409         3
0      307   517         4
```

This works fine but I want to save information about each frame of the video, e.g. the temperature at each frame.

I'm currently doing this by creating a series with the values for each frame and the index containing the frame number then adding the series to the dataframe.

```
prop = pd.Series(temperature_values, 
                 index=pd.Index(np.arange(len(temperature_values)), name='frame')
df['temperature'] = prop
```

This works but produces duplicates of the data in every row of the column:

```
         x     y  particle temperature
frame                     
0      588   840         0          12
0      260   598         1          12
0      297  1245         2          12
0      303   409         3          12
0      307   517         4          12
```

Is there anyway of saving this information without duplicates in the current dataframe so that when I try and get the temperature column I just receive the original series that I created?

If there isn't anyway of doing this my plan is to either deal with the duplicates using drop_duplicates or create a second dataframe with just the data for each frame which I can then merge into my first dataframe but I'd like to avoid doing this if possible.

Here is the current code with jupyter outputs formatted as best as I can:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame()

frames = list(range(5))
for f in frames:
    x = np.random.randint(10, 100, size=10)
    y = np.random.randint(10, 100, size=10)
    particle = np.arange(10)
    data = {
        'x': x,
        'y': y,
        'particle': particle,
        'frame': f}
    df_to_append = pd.DataFrame(data)
    df = df.append(df_to_append)
print(df.head())
```

Output:

```
    x   y  particle  frame
0  61  97         0      0
1  49  73         1      0
2  48  72         2      0
3  59  37         3      0
4  39  64         4      0
```

Input

```
df = df.set_index('frame')
print(df.head())
```

Output

```
        x   y  particle
frame                  
0      61  97         0
0      49  73         1
0      48  72         2
0      59  37         3
0      39  64         4
```

Input:

```
example_data = [10*f for f in frames]
# Current method
prop = pd.Series(example_data, index=pd.Index(np.arange(len(example_data)), name='frame'))
df['data1'] = prop

print(df.head())
print(df.tail())
```

Output:

```
        x   y  particle  data1
frame                         
0      61  97         0      0
0      49  73         1      0
0      48  72         2      0
0      59  37         3      0
0      39  64         4      0
        x   y  particle  data1
frame                         
4      25  93         5     40
4      28  17         6     40
4      39  15         7     40
4      28  47         8     40
4      12  56         9     40
```

Input:

```
# Proposed method
df['data2'] = example_data
```

Output:

```
    ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-e41b12bbe1cd> in <module>
      1 # Proposed method
----> 2 df['data2'] = example_data

~/miniconda3/envs/ParticleTracking/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in __setitem__(self, key, value)
   3368         else:
   3369             # set column
-> 3370             self._set_item(key, value)
   3371 
   3372     def _setitem_slice(self, key, value):

~/miniconda3/envs/ParticleTracking/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in _set_item(self, key, value)
   3443 
   3444         self._ensure_valid_index(value)
-> 3445         value = self._sanitize_column(key, value)
   3446         NDFrame._set_item(self, key, value)
   3447 

~/miniconda3/envs/ParticleTracking/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in _sanitize_column(self, key, value, broadcast)
   3628 
   3629             # turn me into an ndarray
-> 3630             value = sanitize_index(value, self.index, copy=False)
   3631             if not isinstance(value, (np.ndarray, Index)):
   3632                 if isinstance(value, list) and len(value) > 0:

~/miniconda3/envs/ParticleTracking/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/construction.py in sanitize_index(data, index, copy)
    517 
    518     if len(data) != len(index):
--> 519         raise ValueError('Length of values does not match length of index')
    520 
    521     if isinstance(data, ABCIndexClass) and not copy:

ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index
```

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid you cannot. All columns in a DataFrame share the same index and are required to have same length. But coming from the database world, I try to avoid as much as possible indexes with duplicate values.

Comment: Thanks. I often want to access all the rows for each video frame in a loop so having the frame number as the index provides me with a significant performance increase.